# Saving Source of Self (PHP)

Tags: php, file

Okay, so I have this strange problem. And ah, no solution. Can somebody please help me or send me off in the right direction?

I have a simple HTML page, and I need to be able to have a 'Save' button on the page that the user will click. And upon clicking that save button, PHP will then save a copy of the current page the user is on to the same directory on my server.

Is this even possible?x

Thanks!
Any help at all is much appreciated

Comment: Is there anything dynamic on the page that you need to save (stuff changed on the DOM by JS)?

Comment: do you mean php code or html source?

Comment: Errm.. Well, I am using HTML5 and ContentEditable() to enable the user to create their own * on that page. And I have a few lines of Javascript that I use for ContentEditable().

Comment: @JapanPro: I meant the Html source. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're going about this the wrong way. You should probably store the edited content in a database, and serve it up via mod_rewrite rather than writing out a bunch of HTML pages.

Comment: I commented on Capt Otis' answer latnight stating that I am not allowed to use databases for this job.  But my comment isn't there anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to do something with Ajax. If you're using jQuery you could get the entire HTML of the page using `$('body').html()` and send that with an Ajax POST.

Comment: Ah I understand. You need an echoing endpoint. POST the HTML text and bingo you get back the HTML text you can save.

Answer (score 0):

The page can POSTed, using the content at the destination (posted location).

It can be posted using HTML (submit button (and text area, for example)), or JavaScript (or JQuery).
It can be received by PHP or another language.

For example (HTML and PHP):

HTML:

```
<form>  
    <textarea name="content">  
    </textarea>  

   <input type="submit">  
</form>
```

PHP:

```
// Use $_POST ["content"]
```

Comment: I do not know if you can post using any other way, so I excluded mentioning this in the answer.