# Saving html page in local storage using php

Tags: php, html, pdf-to-html

I am using **PDFTOHTML** (a php library) to convert pdf files to html and it's working fine but it's showing converted file in a browser and not storing in local folder, i want to store converted html in local folder using php with the same name as pdf was i-e **mydata.pdf** to **mydata.html** 
Code that is converting pdf to html is:-

```
 <?php
// if you are using composer, just use this
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

 $pdf = new \TonchikTm\PdfToHtml\Pdf('cv.pdf', [
     'pdftohtml_path' => 'C:/wamp64/www/new/poppler-0.51/bin/pdftohtml.exe',
    'pdfinfo_path' => 'C:/wamp64/www/new/poppler-0.51/bin/pdfinfo.exe'
]);

// get content from all pages and loop for they
foreach ($pdf->getHtml()->getAllPages() as $page) {
    echo $page . '<br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: In this case $page is what you want to save as html file or i wrong?

Comment: @SiderTopalov yes i want to store $page

Comment: Does that $page or $pdf->getHtml()->getAllPages() return you any file name?

Comment: @SiderTopalov it shows the converted html in a browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your foreach to

```
$filePdf = 'cv'; // your pdf filename without extension
$pdf = new \TonchikTm\PdfToHtml\Pdf($filePdf.'.pdf', [
    'pdftohtml_path' => 'C:/wamp64/www/new/poppler-0.51/bin/pdftohtml.exe',
    'pdfinfo_path' => 'C:/wamp64/www/new/poppler-0.51/bin/pdfinfo.exe'
]);

$counterPage = 1;
foreach ($pdf->getHtml()->getAllPages() as $page) {
    $filename = $filePdf . "_" . $counterPage.'.html'; // set as string directory and filename where you want to save it

    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        // if file exist do something
    } else {
        // else 
        $fileOpen = fopen($filename, 'w+');
        fputs($fileOpen, $page);
        fclose($fileOpen);
    }
    $counterPage++;
    echo $page . '<br/>';
}
```

This will create you file for example: example_1.html, example_2.html and so on.
if this not help you then probably you need to use file_put_contents with ob_start() and ob_get_contents() [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775281/save-current-page-as-html-to-server)

Comment: showing error
`( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.html'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\wamp64\www\new\example.php` and we have to define name of html every time we pass a pdf to it, is there any with which it can get the pdf name through code?

Comment: yea I forgot to put "." Change fopen($filename'.html', 'w+'); to fopen($filename.'.html', 'w+');

Comment: About name of html.. Does your pdf file content one page or more than one

Comment: sometimes there is only one page but mostly there are two

Comment: Does your pdf content separeted names for each page inside?

Comment: Then you can do something like that check my answer again i will modified it now

Comment: it is only saving first page not second

Comment: Delete all created pages then try again if is not saving your second page then this mean that it enter in if case not else case checkout your code i think you can do it

Comment: brother i'av tried but still second page not showing, u were of great help for me it would be great if you just do me this favour ,thanks!!

Comment: Please var_dump($filename) for me and link it below to see what names are building

Comment: okay where do you want me to var_dump it?
and as i am working on local right now i will share you a screenshot of output is that okay?

Comment: Before you share me a screen shot check my code and make sure is the same as your like variable names and other thinks and try again and then if you still get the same problem share me a screenshot of output

Comment: This work for me please make sure you are not missing something

Comment: Now it's storing both pages in different html i-e **1 page to cv_1.html and 2 page to cv_2.html** now i'll try to store data of both pages into one html page
Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Look this :

```
<?php
// if you are using composer, just use this
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
$pdf = new \TonchikTm\PdfToHtml\Pdf('cv.pdf', ['pdftohtml_path' => 'C:/wamp64/www/new/poppler-0.51/bin/pdftohtml.exe', 'pdfinfo_path' => 'C:/wamp64/www/new/poppler-0.51/bin/pdfinfo.exe']);
// get content from all pages and loop for they
$file = fopen('cv.html', 'w+');
$data = null;
foreach ($pdf->getHtml()->getAllPages() as $page) {
    $data .= "".$page."<br/>";
}
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

I did not test this code

Comment: @simon511000 yes it is storing it in local but in this we have to define name of html every time we pass a pdf to it, is there any with which it can get the pdf name through code?