# Change Default Download Location in Php

Tags: php, header, http-headers

I want to change default download location in php
Using header function I cant' find a parameter for that
This is the definition of header

```
header(string $header, bool $replace = true, int $response_code = 0)
```

Edit:
URL of solution
[Save current page as HTML to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775281/save-current-page-as-html-to-server)

```
<?php
// Start the buffering //
ob_start();
?>
```

Your page content

```
<?php
echo '1';
file_put_contents('yourpage.html', ob_get_contents());
?>
```

Instead of yourpage.html you specifiy the path and it works
Is there any solution for header or other alternative to just change default download location
Thanks

Comment: I'd be surprised if this was possible - that's a client/user thing

Comment: How are you gonna address different OSes? How would you handle the download location not existing on a client machine?

Comment: I will create it , it is a directory in the project (on xampp)

Comment: Luckily, web sites don't have that degree of control over the browser. For a start, there's no way to know how the user's hard disk drive is set up. But I'm sure it would be easily exploitable to download malware.

Comment: Is there a way to convert this function to other alternative

Comment: header('Content-Disposition:attachement;filename=fichier.html ' , I need to add specific location in project

Comment: This is a client-side feature so you probably need some sort of client-side solution such as a browser extension or something like that.

Comment: There is buffer solution but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: "There is buffer solution" - what does that mean? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score -2):

URL of solution
[Save current page as HTML to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775281/save-current-page-as-html-to-server)

```
<?php
// Start the buffering //
ob_start();
?>
```

Your page content

```
<?php
echo '1';
file_put_contents('yourpage.html', ob_get_contents());
?>
```

Instead of yourpage.html you specifiy the path and it works

Comment: That won't trigger a download to the computer of the user of that website

Comment: It will do that , I have tested it

Comment: What have you tested? It's completely impossible that running this code changes any file on any other computer than the server handling the request

Comment: That's because you're testing it in your own computer, most likely with an administrator user, so server and client are the same computer.